# On countable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]I cant quite understand why $S$ is countable. Is it countable because it is mapped to a countable set which is $T$? $T$ i know is countable since it is an infinite subset of a countable set which is the set of positive integers.

Thanks for the help.

I got his from rudin's principle of mathematical analysis.

Comment: I think that in the last para Rudin is trying to deal with the difficulty that the same element might appear in multiple $E_n$. So it is a two stage process: (A) the sequence (17) - which may contain many duplicates - is countable; and hence (B) the set $S$ (from which duplicates have been eliminated) is countable. Of course, (B) is obvious given (A), which makes it a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It is countable for exactly the same reason that Rudin states it is. It's countable because there's a bijection $\mathbb{N} \to S$ which is described as writing these sequences out in rows and going about them diagonally. Eventually, for large enough integers, all members of the union are reached.

Comment: This is the case wherein members of $S$ are distinct. Im interested in the case wherein elements of $S$ are not distinct.

Comment: @IsaacNewton If the union is not disjoint, then the resulting set is even smaller, hence also countable.

Comment: If $E_i\cap E_j\neq \emptyset$ for some $i,j$, then the constructed sequence might contain certain elements multiple times. Simply remove all those elements you don't need. You will still have something countable (answer yourself why the sequence cannot become finite).

Comment: @Tobias Ah. OK. Thanks. Can i ask if a set $A$ has a 1-1 correspondence with a countable set. Does that make $A$ countable?

Comment: @IsaacNewton, Consider $S_n=E_n\setminus\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}E_i$. Then, all the $S_n$'s are pairwise disjoint but $\bigcup\limits_n S_n=\bigcup\limits_n E_n$

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong:

An attempt:

Let $(E_n)_{ n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of countable sets.

All elements of $S := \displaystyle \cup E_n$ can be arranged as shown in the array.

The array can be arranged as a sequence:

$x_{11},x_{21},x_{12},x_{31},x_{22},...$

Means we could define $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow S:$

$f(1)=x_{11};f(2)=x_{21}; f(3)=x_{12},.$

Note : $f$ may not(!) be injective since any two sets $E_n$ may have the same element. Hence one distinct element may have been counted more than once.

Now:

There is $T \subset  \mathbb{N}$ such that

($T$ is countable as a subset of $\mathbb{N}$)

$T \sim S$, i.e. there exists a bijection(!) $g$:

$g: T \rightarrow S.$

Hence :

1)$S$ is at most countable.

2) $E_1\subset S$ , $E_1$ infinite, hence $S$ countable.

Remark:

$f$ is not necessarily an injection.

Hence: Rudin goes back to $T$ to find an injection (bijection) $g:  T \rightarrow S.$

Does this help?

Comment: So the main reason why $S$ is countable is that there exist a bijective function between $S$ and a countable set which is $T$?

Comment: Isaac.Rudin defines countable by it, look it up.S could look like S={1,7,5,1,90,1}. 'To get rid of the doubles ' he goes back to T. Note:S={1,1,2,3,3,6,7}={1,2,3,6,7}, so how to get rid of the doubles ?(loosely speaking) when the set is the same.Your thoughts?

Comment: Yup. Rudin defined a countable set to be a set which is in bijection with the set of positive integers. But the thing here is that $S$ is in bijection with just a subset of theset of positive integers.